# How to insert multiple rows from different tables into one table?

Tags: sql, select, insert, rows

I want to insert different rows like

```
SDESC from COMPANY
NAME from DISTRIBUTOR
WAREHOUSE from WAREHOUSE
SDESC from WAREHOUSE
LDESC from WAREHOUSE
STOCK_ALLOCATION from WAREHOUSE
```

into a table `STAGING_WAREHOUSE` which has following columns

```
COMPANY_NAME
DISTRIBUTOR
WAREHOUSE
SDESC
LDESC
STOCK_ALLOCATION
```

Comment: And what is exactly your problem? What have you tried? Also, what DB are you using (Oracle, MySQL, etc.)?

Comment: please mention the relation between Company,Distributor,WareHouse...etc table

Answer (score 0):

Insert data to corresponding tables and then create a view `STAGING_WAREHOUSE`

To create a view

```
CREATE VIEW STAGING_WAREHOUSE AS
SELECT COMPANY.COMPANY_NAME, COMPANY.SDESC, DISTRIBUTOR.NAME, WAREHOUSE.WAREHOUSE, WAREHOUSE.SDESC, WAREHOUSE.LDESC, WAREHOUSE.STOCK_ALLOCATION
FROM COMPANY, DISTRIBUTOR, WAREHOUSE WHERE COMPANY.SDESC = WAREHOUSE.SDESC
```